# VS 2013 shows code not running when any break point is hit?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2013 when I put any break point in my code it sometimes shows "Code Not Running". Please see the picture below:

[image]

When I have put break point on Form1_Load() method it shows this thing but when I put on constructor is debugging easily.

Can anybody help me how to debug this code?